# how to return block or unificate table rendering (activeadmin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have some different sets of active record. Each record set is rendered with identical code.

The original code looks like this:

```
columns do
  column do
    panel "Panel" do
      table_for Record.where( ... ) do
        column("id")    {|r| r.id }
        column("field") {|r| r.field }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I actually want something like this:

```
# (wrong code) (EDIT: actually work fine - it is not wrong)

def render_table(records)
  table_for records do
    column("id")    {|r| r.id }
    column("field") {|r| r.field }
  end
end

panel "Panel" { render_table Record.where( ... ) }
```

As well as like this too:

```
# ( wrong code )

def render_table_fields
  render lambda do
    column("id")    {|r| r.id }
    column("field") {|r| r.field }
  end
end

panel "Panel" do
  table_for Record.where( ... ) { render_table_fields.call }
end
```

How do I refactor to extract table rendering code?

How to return block or lambda from function and pass it as block to another function?

Comment: Your first "wrong code" looks like it ought to work, except method arguments can't begin with a capital letter. What problem are you having?

Comment: Thanks frinds! I have try number of solutions (seems first example too) with no success. Seems it was confuse (I have no try first example). First example worked fine. So only one question is here. How to return block or lambda from function and pass it as block to another function?